# To fault or not to fault

Tags: wcf, exception, architecture, faults

I'm having a discussion with a colleague about when to throw faults and when not to throw faults in a WCF service.

One opinion is, that we only throw faults when the service operation could not do its work due to some error; and something may be in an invalid state because of it. So, some examples:

- ValidateMember(string name, string password, string country) 
  -> would throw a fault if the mandatory parameters are not passed, because the validation itself could not be executed;
  -> would throw fault if some internal error occured, like database was down
  -> would return a status contract in all other cases, that specifies the result of the validation (MemberValidated, WrongPassword, MemberNotKnown,...)
- GetMember(int memberId)
  -> would only throw fault if something is down, in all other cases it would return the member or null if not found

The other opinion is that we should also throw faults when GetMember does not find the member, or in the case of ValidateMember the password is wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: By the way, if you upvote people who provide useful answers on occasion, then perhaps you'll get more people answering your questions

Comment: can't do that, upvote requires 15 reputation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My take on this...

There are three causes of failure:

1. The service code threw an exception, e.g. database error, logic error in your code. This is your fault.
2. The client code failed to use your service properly according to your documentation, e.g. it didn't set a required flag value, it failed to pass in an ID. This is the client software developer's fault.
3. The end user typed in something silly on screen, e.g. missing date of birth, negative salary. This is the end user's fault.

It's up to you how you choose to map actual fault contracts to each cause of failure. For example, we do this:

- For causes 1 and 2, all the client code needs to know is that the service failed. We define a very simple "fatal error" fault contract that contains only a unique error ID. The full details of the error are logged on the server.
- For cause 3, the end user needs to know exactly what he/she did wrong. We define a "validation errors" fault contract containing a collection of friendly error messages for the client code to display on screen.

We borrow the [Microsoft EntLib class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.integration.wcf.validationfault.aspx) for cause 3, and use [exception shielding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling.wcf.exceptionshieldingattribute.aspx) to handle causes 1 and 2 declaratively. It makes for very simple code.

**To Clarify:**

We handle the three causes like this inside the service:

1. An unexpected exception is thrown in the service code. We catch it at the top level (actually exception shielding catches it, but the principle is the same). Log full details, then throw a `FaultException<ServiceFault>` to the client containing only the error ID.
2. We validate the input data and deliberately throw an exception. It's normally an `ArgumentException`, but any appropriate type would do. Once it is thrown, it is dealt with in exactly the same way as (1) because we want to make it appear the same to the client.
3. We validate the input data and deliberately throw an exception. This time, it's a `FaultException<ValidationFault>`. We configure exception shielding to pass this one through un-wrapped, so it appears on the client as `FaultException<ValidationFault>` not `FaultException<ServiceFault>`.

End result:

- No catch blocks at all inside the service (nice clean code).
- Client only has to catch `FaultException<ValidationFault>` if it wants to display messages to the user. All other exception types including `FaultException<ServiceFault>` are dealt with by the client's global error handler as fatal errors, since a fatal error in the service generally means a fatal error in the client as well.

Comment: ok, so all these cases relate to invalid input data, in that case we also throw faults. But what would you do in the other cases?

Comment: I've added more details. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I see how you handle the exceptions and faults, thanks. Would you throw a fault in the case of GetCustomer when some customer id is passed but not found when the repository tries to find it, or not?

Comment: I would say that it's cause 2. The client code has passed in bad data, but the end user doesn't enter raw IDs on screen, so it must be the developer's fault.

Answer (score 3):

It it is a common, routine failure, then throwing a fault is a mistake.  The software should be written to handle routine items, like entering the wrong password.  Fault processing is for exceptional failure which are not considered part of the program's normal design.

For example, if your program was written with the idea that it always has access to a database, and the database is not accessible, that's an issue where the "fix" is well outside of the limits of your software.  A fault should be thrown.

Fault processing uses different logical flows through the structure of the programming language, and by using it only when you've "left" the normal processing of the programming problem, you will make your solution leverage the feature of the programming language in a way that seems more natural.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is good practice to separate error handling and fault handling. Any error case should be dealt by your program - fault handling is reserved for exceptional conditions. As a guide to the separation of the two I found it useful when considering such cases to remember that there are only three types of error (when handling data and messages) and only one type of fault.
The error types are related to different types of validation:

1. Message validation - you can determine from the message contents that the data is valid or invalid.

   Example: content that is intended to be a date of birth - you can tell from the data whether it is valid or not.
2. Context validation - you can only determine that content is invalid by reference to the message
   combined with the system state.

   Example: a valid date of joining a company is earlier than that persons date of birth.
3. Lies to the system - you can only determine that a message was in error when a later message
   throws up an anomaly.

   Example: Valid date of birth stored and inspection of the person's birth certificate shows this to be incorrect. Correction of lies to the system generally require action outside of the system, for instance invoking legal or disciplinary remedies.

Your system MUST deal with all classes of error - though in case three this may be limited to issuing an alert.

Faults (exceptions) by contrast only have one cause - data corruption (which includes data truncation).  Example: validation parameters are not passed.

Here the appropriate mechanism is fault or exception handling - basically handing off the problem to some other part of the system that is capable of dealing with it (which is why there should be an ultimate destination for unhandled faults).

Answer (score 2):

In the old days we used to have a rule that exceptions were only for exceptional and unexpected things. One of the reasons you did not want to use them too much was that they "cost" alot of computing power.

But if you use exceptions you can reduce the amount of code, no need for alot of if else statements, just let the exception bubble up.

It depends on your project. The most important thing is that there is a project standard and everyone does it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that exceptions/fault should be thrown whenever what the method is supposed to do can't be achieved. So validation logic should never raise exception except if the validation can't be made (i.e. for technical reasons) but never just because the data are not valid (in that case it will return validation codes/messages or anything helping the caller to correct the data).

Now the GetMember case is an interesting one because it's all about semantic. The name of the method suggest that a member can be retrieved by passing an id (compare to a TryGetMember method for exemple). Of course the method should not throw the same exception if the id is nowhere to be found or if the database does not respond but a wrong id passed to this method is probably the sign that something is going wrong somewhere before that call. Except if the user can directly enter a member-id from within the interface in which case a validation should occurred before calling the method.

I hear a lot about the performance issue. I just made a simple test using C# and trow/catch 1000 exceptions. The time it took is 23ms for 1K Exeptions. That's 23µ per exception. I think performance is no longer the first argument here except if you plan to raise more than 2000 exception per second in which case you will have a 5% performance down, which I can start considering.

My humble opinion...